# Sync data onchain in Solana in backend

Tags: web3.js, developer

I am new to Sol development. I have been working with EVM for the past two years. I want to sync data in my smart contract in the backend. For this, I know I can use the filter event function in Etherjs to get events. However, I am not sure how to do this using Solana web3js. Can anyone guide me on this? Thanks for all.

Comment: Please be more specific about what type of data you're trying to listen for.